# Transformar linhas em colunas - PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

Possuo a seguinte `Query`:

```
SELECT 
    public.tipocontratoempresa.codigoempresa, 
    CAST ((public.tipocontratoempresa.quantidadehorasmensais * 3) AS Integer) as horastrimestrais, 
    to_char(public.dadosmensaisfaturamentos.datainicial, 'MONTH') AS mes,
    public.dadosmensaisfaturamentos.tempototal, 
    public.dadosmensaisfaturamentos.valortotal
FROM 
    public.tipocontratoempresa,
    public.tiposcontratos,
    public.dadosmensaisfaturamentos
where 
    public.tipocontratoempresa.status = true and
    public.tipocontratoempresa.codigotipocontrato = public.tiposcontratos.codigotipocontrato and
    public.dadosmensaisfaturamentos.codigoempresa = public.tipocontratoempresa.codigoempresa and
    DATE_PART('MONTH', public.dadosmensaisfaturamentos.datainicial) between 7 and 9 and
    public.tipocontratoempresa.codigoempresa = 'CRF'
order by 
    public.tipocontratoempresa.codigoempresa,
    DATE_PART('MONTH', public.dadosmensaisfaturamentos.datainicial)
```

Que me retorna os dados da seguinte forma:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Consigo converter as linhas em colunas? Para que fique o retorno mais ou menos assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Vc pode tentar usar a função do [crosstab](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/tablefunc.html) do postgreSQL, da uma sacada nesse link, uso muito esse recurso

Comment: conseguiu resolver R.Santos ?